# Qt - How to save data for my application

Tags: c++, qt, save, restore, custom-type

I'm pretty new to Qt and I have a problem with finding out how to save/load data from your application.

I'm creating a Calendar app and have to save different classes like: Deathlines, appointments, birthdays, etc.

And I've found this tutorial http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/tutorials-addressbook-part6.html but it only describes how to save one type of class.

So I was wondering if you could help me, because I have no idea how to save/load multiple classes that way, I don't need some detailed description of it (however it would be appreciated of course) but only a gentle push into the right direction.

Because nowhere in this tutorial is explained how to save multiple classes :(

*EDIT: This program is for PC (project for school)*

Comment: Do you need to save the data in a platform-independent way? If so you could use a structured format such as [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) or [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), which allows multiple "types" of data in a single file.

Comment: I'm creating this for PC, sorry i should have told that yes, but I can take a look at this XML or JSON anyways, thank you

Comment: Hi, as far as I know, I see two ways to store data: database and files. The example you saw is about read/write in a file, this is not proper to Qt. You can write what you want in a file, you just have to define you protocol. However, using xml could be nice instead of a custom protocol of your own.

Comment: So I can just load/save that XML class with the same way as in the tutorial? (with a QIODevice/ QDataStream)

Comment: It's not a Xml class. Xml (Extensible Markup Language) is a language. I'll give you an example, if you want to store an appointment, you can have a class Appointment with two attributes (where and when). To store it in an xml file, you use QtXml (with QDomDocument) and you could create an Xml file like this `<Appointment><Where>here</Where><When>15-Jan-2015</When></Appointment>`. When you will rerun your app, you can load your file with all of your appointments. You can create N xml files (one for each class) or 1 xml file storing N classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define your custom class and implement stream operators for it :

```
class CustomType
{
public:

    CustomType()
    {
        paramter1=0;
        paramter2=0;
        paramter3="";

    }
    ~CustomType(){}

    int paramter1;
    double parameter2;
    QString parameter3;
};


inline QDataStream& operator<<( QDataStream &out, const CustomType& t )
{
    out<<t.paramter1;
    out<<t.paramter2;
    out<<t.paramter3;


    return out;
}
inline QDataStream& operator>>( QDataStream &in, CustomType& t)
{
    in>>t.paramter1;
    in>>t.paramter2;
    in>>t.paramter3;

    return in;
}
```

You should register the stream operators of your class somewhere in your code when starting your application before streaming the class. This could be done in the constructor of your main window :

```
qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<CustomType>("CustomType");
```

Now you can save or load objects of your class to or from file.

Saving some objects of your custom classes to a file :

```
QFile file(fileName);
if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
         QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Unable to open file"),
             file.errorString());
         return;
 }


 QDataStream out(&file);
 out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_8);
 out << object1;
 out << object2;
```

loading objects of your custom classes from a file :

```
QFile file(fileName);
 if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
         QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Unable to open file"),
             file.errorString());
         return;
 }


  QDataStream in(&file);
  in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_8);
  in >> object1;
  in >> object2;
```

Note that the order of reading and writing to file should be the same.

Comment: Hi Nejat, as you probably see, I suggest writing in file using xml. Don't you think your solution could be dangerous ? If I understand well, if you store an integer, a double and a QString, when reading you'll read 4 bytes, 8 bytes, and N bytes till '\0' ? In that case, what if you store a QByteArray with several '\0' in it ? I tried some tricky values to store in Xml and had no problem but I'm little perplexe with yours. Convince me :p ?

Comment: Would it be safe to use if I change the int/double/QString with a QList<Appointment>, QList<Deathline>, ... ?

Comment: @Martinad  `QString` is serialized such that it carries its own length with it. There is no problem when you are dealing with Qt data types.

Comment: @Dennis You can also stream Qt containers this way.