# QT Creator - How can I store/save selected file to project directory

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qfiledialog, qfile

I am trying to create a way to store file's in the project directory. I am using `QFileDialog` for the dialog and using `Qfile::copy()` to copy the selected file. I was able to get it to work by storing it outside the project directory (Desktop). But for this, I need it to store in the project directory.

I am more than happy to provide additional information if needed.

**Note: I tried storing it in the Resource folder as well without success. BTW, I am new to qt development world.**

```
QString filePath = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, QObject::tr("PDF files"),
                                                "C:/", "PDF (*.pdf) ;; JPG (*.jpg) ;; PNG (*.png)");

QFileInfo file(filePath);
QString fileName= file.fileName();

if(QFile::copy(filePath, ":/PDF/PDF/"+fileName))
    qDebug() << "success";
else
    qDebug() << "FAILED TO LOAD TO -> :/PDF/PDF/"+fileName;
```

Comment: You can not add something to your compiled-in resources. They're read-only.

Comment: I don't get what you want to achieve, but what about using the executable file path ? (QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath())

Comment: @chehrlic, I did some digging and found this stack answer. Could you confirm to me if it would achieve what I am looking to do (save selected files to directory) https://stackoverflow.com/a/25114190/7938426

Comment: @Yoruk in simplest terms, I am trying to just save user-selected files into the project directory similar to how it's done on web development. or at least have the program create a writable directory to then store files in it...?

Comment: Depending on how your project is managed, but in my projects the executables files are stored into a "debug" or "release" folder into my project folder. By getting the executable folder and going on the parent folder, you may land into your project directory...?

Comment: When you say "project directory", it sounds like you're saying the directory with your source files that you are building from. There's no such thing as a "project directory" in the context of running the application. The application can be run from any path (even a different machine) and might not even be able to access the directory that it was built from. The only answer that makes sense here is as @Yoruk suggested to use `QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()` which is where the executable is located.

Comment: If you want to store some data you should use [QStandardPaths::wirteableLocation(QStandardPaths::DataLocation)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html#writableLocation) - all other directories may not be writeable when you properly install your program e.g. in C:\Program Files or similar.

Comment: @chehrlic your suggestions worked for me. Was able to write any selected file to the path.

Comment: @JarMan your comment helped me understand and realize that I can't write to the project directory.